# Memcached: How can I modify maximum item size?

Tags: node.js, memcached

I'm newbie in Memcached. By defualt, I know that the minimum item size is 1MB. However, I want to increase this value to 4MB because I've got an item with 2.8MB size.

Following some instructions I have edited my /etc/memcached.conf file and add this entry: -I 4MB

[image]

After add this entry, I have saved the file and restart memcached with:
sudo service memcached restart

Checking the variable of configuration with this command:
echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211

I can see that the value of item_size_max setting to 4MB (4194304)

[image]

But, If I try to load information in memcached after restart the server, I'v got an error when I try to insert an item with more than 1MB.

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my configuration? How can I add items to memcached with more than 1MB of size?

My memcached version is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [memcached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached?activeTab=readme) package has a bunch of default props so you need to set the `maxValue` to 4m too. Passing in an options object when setting up the client will do the job:

```js
const Memcached = require('memcached');
const memcached = new Memcached('localhost:11211', {maxValue:4194304});
```

Or you can do this globally:

```js
const Memcached = require('memcached');
Memcached.config.maxValue = 4194304;
const memcached = new Memcached('localhost:11211');
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to answer of @Will from [Increase Memcached Max Item Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194955/increase-memcached-max-item-size)

You could try in command prompt

```
memcached -I 4M -u
```

-u is used to specify the user under which Memcached should run

Or

```
memcached -d -m 512 -I 4m
```

Where:
-d memcached using this flag, it runs in the background as a service
-m Maximum memory used by memcached